# The behavior of pure sheaves under functor Hom( F, -)

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology

We know that a submodule A of B is pure if and only if the functor $Hom(M, -)$ is exact on the sequence
$ 0 \rightarrow A \rightarrow B \rightarrow C \rightarrow 0$
for every finitely presented module M.
So, let X be a scheme and ${\cal G}$ be a subsheaf of ${\cal H}$. Is there any equivalent statement for pure sheaves. ($\cal G$ is pure in $\cal H$, if ${\cal G}(U)$ is pure in ${\cal H}(U)$ for every affine open subset U of X.)

Comment: Perhaps you should assume $X$ to be qs qc to get the affine criterion out of a more general one.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by qs qc scheme. May you explain me more details, please?

Answer (score 2):

Let $\mathbf{A}$ be a cocomplete abelian category, such as any category of sheaves. An object $M$ is *finitely presented* if the representable functor $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbf{A}}(M,-)$ preserves filtered colimits. Now that you know what a finitely presentable object is, just mimick the definition you know of pure subobject. All this is standard.